# How to export data stored in GG Bigquery into GZ file.

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, export

I used this code to export data into a csv file and it works:

```
project_id = 'project_id'
client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_id = 'dataset_id'
bucket_name = 'bucket_name'
table_id = 'table_id'

destination_uri = 'gs://{}/{}'.format(bucket_name, 'file.csv')
dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id, project=project_id)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

extract_job = client.extract_table(
    table_ref,
    destination_uri) 
extract_job.result()
```

But I prefer a GZ file because of my table up to 700M. Could anyone help me export data into a GZ file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a `jobConfig` like in:

```
job_config = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig()
job_config.compression = 'GZIP'
```

Complete code:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()

project_id = 'fh-bigquery'
dataset_id = 'public_dump'
table_id = 'afinn_en_165'


bucket_name = 'your_bucket'

destination_uri = 'gs://{}/{}'.format(bucket_name, 'file.csv.gz')

dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id, project=project_id)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

job_config = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig()
job_config.compression = 'GZIP'
extract_job = client.extract_table(
    table_ref,
    destination_uri,
    job_config = job_config
) 
extract_job.result()
```

Comment: Would you post a new question?